# EC2 instance state return pending even when it is running in a lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I made a lambda function to manage EC2 instances. To create the instance I use this code in the lambda function:

```
instance = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='eu-west-3').Instance(instance_id)
```

To know the instance state, I get the state code as following:

```
code = instance.state['Code']
```

When the instance is stopped, the code is 80, then, I can use instance.start() to launch the instance. Inmediately after that the code become 0 (pending) while the instance is launching. The problem is, when I see the instance already running in the EC2 console, the function still returning code 0 instead of code 16 (running). But, if I deploy again the lambda function and run it, now yes, I got code 16, anyone knows the reason of this behaviour?

Comment: You need to provide full lambda code.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the [`instance.load()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Instance.load) method to update the status, otherwise it is just retrieving the previous result:

> Calls `EC2.Client.describe_instances()` to update the attributes of the `Instance` resource. Note that the load and reload methods are the same method and can be used interchangeably.